# Add different controls in different rows in UI5 table

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I have table `sap.ui.table.Table` ans I have a model in which some records have links and some doesn't. I want to render the link in the `sap.m.Link` component in the column and when the link is not available in the record, it should render "Link is not provided." in the `sap.m.Text` in the column.

As the `sap.ui.table.Column` has the template aggregation which does not support binding aggregation as it is only 0 or 1 controls supported. And the formatter is also applicable here. Is there any way that  the content of the column can be changed runtime according to the module data?

My module data is :

```
var data = [{
   id : 1,
   link : 'abc.com'
},
{
   id : 2
},
{
   id : 3,
   link : 'pqr.com'
}]
```

I am providing the code:

```
var link = new sap.m.Link({text : "{link}"});
var noLink = new sap.m.Text({text : "Link is not provided."});

var idColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label : [new sap.m.Label({text : "ID"})],
    template : [new sap.m.Text({text : "{id}"})]
});

var linkColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
   label : [new sap.m.Label({text : "Link"})],
   template : [??????]
});

var table = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    columns : [idColumn, linkColumn]
});

var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
model.setData({items : data});
table.setModel(model);
table.bindRows("/items");
```

I want to add the `link` and `noLink` in the column `likColumn` runtime according to the data in the module. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please clarify: 1. Do you need 2 columns or one column and based on link availbility, show it as sap.m.Link or sap.m.Text? 2. Or, do you want 2 separate columns?

Comment: Also, look at this issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/866 . It is not possible to have different controls in separate rows of sap.ui.table.table. However, it is possible in sap.m.Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display content of each column can be changed using `formatter`

e.g:

```
   new sap.m.Link({
      width: "20em",
      //editable: false,
      //text: "{items>link}"   
      text: {
        path: "items>link",
        formatter: function(link){
          if (link === undefined) return "Link is not provided"
          return link;
        }
      }
    });

...

oTable.addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function(){
        $('#idTable a:contains("Link is not provided")').removeClass("sapMLnk");
    }
}, oTable);
```

**UPDATE:** This is a jsbin with the full example of what you need:
[UPDATED example](https://jsbin.com/serume/edit?js,output)

Comment: I want to add `sap.m.Text` in the column when the link is not available and `sap.m.Link` when the link is available.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible but you can change the behavior of the sap.m.Link element to be like sap.m.Text in that case, you can do it in `onAfterRendering` function. See the updated example.

Comment: Ok I can try this. Thanks for help!!